# How to get an object from HTML in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'd like to get a project from a list of projects and use that object in another component. I'm not sure how to do this. Below is my HTML code.

```
<li *ngFor = "let project of projects" class="list-group-item">{{project.name}} {{project._id}}>
<a [routerLink]="['/tasks']">View Tasks</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/newTask']" (click)="getAllTasks(project)">Create Task</a>
```

update: I might try to use a service to do this.

```
    setProjectId(project){
    this.authService.setProjectId(project._id);
}
```

send the object to the service, when clicked.

```
    setProjectId(id){
    this.project_id = id;
  }



getProjectId(){
    return this.project_id;
  }
```

and get the id in the other component with ngInit()

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProjectId().subscribe(data => {
      this.project_id = data;
    },
    err =>{
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Crucial to be able to provide you with an answer: What is the relationship between this component and the other component?

Comment: This component just displays projects, so when i click a link on a specific project to create a task, I want to be re-routed to that component and use that specific project_id to create a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you used the `project` variable in `getAllTasks()`, you can set an input on the component that you want to use the object in, and bind the `project` variable to that input property.

Comment: One question: is the component within your li, or is it on a separate template? Because if it is separate, then it is easiest to use a service.

Comment: In the template, bind the variable to the input as follows: `<my-component [myProject]="project"></my-component>`. In the component code, just declare a variable an input by `@Input() myProject: any;`

Comment: That would work if it is inside the li tag, but it may be on a separate html template, so then using a service would be better.

Comment: Elucius' answer is correct if the component relationship is parent-child. Otherwise a different solution is needed.

Comment: How would suggest using a service for this? @G.Ross

Comment: It depends what data you want to transfer. If you wanted to use a specific project object based on an event (click etc.) then you could set a variable in the service that would be read by the other component. For a specific project, you could set a variable for the index of the array, and use that value to get the project out of the original array (also stored in the service). You would just need to make sure it is the same instance  (an easy way of doing this is adding this service to the providers array of the app module, so the entire application has the same instance).

Comment: @G.Ross please see updated question. Something like this should work?

Comment: Yes that should work. Just make sure you don't have two separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this as follows :

```
<li *ngFor = "let project of projects" class="list-group-item" (click)="emitObject(project)">{{project.name}} {{project._id}}></li>
```

and now in your ts file you could define a new Event Emitter like so:

```
@Output()
selectedProject = new EventEmitter<any>;

emitObject(project) {
    this.selectedProject.emit(project);
}
```

this will emit an event which you can listen to in an html and then perform the business logic.

you could also pass it to the component as an input property if you happen to use that component in you html of this component.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment...

> This component just displays projects, so when i click a link on a specific project to create a task, I want to be re-routed to that component and use that specific project_id to create a task

... the cleanest solution in my opinion would be to add a query parameter to your route:

route snippet: `{path: 'newTask/:id', component: NewTaskComponent }`

In your NewTaskComponent you can get the id as followed:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private taskService: TaskService) {
  activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    params => {
      if (params['id'] != undefined) {
        taskService.getTaskById(params['id']).subscribe(
          result => console.log(result),
          error => console.log(error)
        );
      }
    }
}
```

This would require you to make a taskService that can get a task by id.